# How do I search for text strings in multiple PHP files?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

Long story short, I got a folder with nearly 800,000 php files. I would like to search each file for a string and if it exists in that file, the file gets copied to another directory.

Is this possible from the terminal?

So far I got:

> grep -i -n -r 'ppr-1792' * | cp $1 move_to_here

But this obviously doesn't work. $1 needs to be the file name that contains matching text.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop and test the return code of grep, or use `grep -c` (count matches) and see if the match count is greater than 1.

e.g.

```
for i in *
do
    grep -i -n 'Power' "$i"

    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
    then
            cp "$i" mvd
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the error "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'". I'm pasting that directly into the terminal. Is that correct?

Comment: To be safe, you should probably quote all variables; e.g.: "$i"

Comment: Oh, and you forgot the `; then` after the (what should be) `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`

Comment: sorry, where does the ';' go? after "done"?

Comment: Think I got it. Need a "then" keyword in there, too

Comment: As I said, my bash is **rusty** haha. Thanks guys.

Comment: `if grep -inqs 'Power' "$i"; then`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with a nice one liner:

`grep -l -i -r -Z pattern | xargs -0 -I source cp source /target`

Some comments how it works. Grep's -l option prints just a file name if there is a match in the file, so it produces a list of files to be copied. Xargs command constructs a command for each copy command and executes it. Xargs replaces argument named "source" with a file name read from standard input. Spaces and other funny characters in file names are handled with -Z and -0 options.

Comment: +1 One small improvement: use ack (or ack-grep) instead of grep. Ack is a lot faster and supports perl regex.

Comment: @mehaase: You're right, ack is really good for greping source files!